# Scala: how to extend an immutable List

Tags: scala, implicit, sealed

Many methods of a program receive as parameter a List[Map[String, String]].

I'd like to formalize it and make it more readable by defining a class such as:

```
class MyClass extends  List[Map[String, String]]
```

However it throws an error:

```
Illegal inheritance from sealed class 'List'
```

Is there a proper way to handle it?

Comment: You can use a type alias: `type MyType = List[Map[String, String]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing you need is called a type alias:

```
type MyClass = List[Map[String, String]]
```

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-type-aliases-syntax-examples

You get the error because you're trying to extend a sealed trait which can be only extended in the same file in which the trait is defined.

https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-type-aliases-syntax-examples
https://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/06/02/everything-about-sealed.html

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [composition rather than inheritance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance):

```
case class MyClass(value: List[Map[String, String]])
```

This is more type-safe than using a type alias, as you can only pass an instance of `MyClass` where `MyClass` is expected, whereas the type alias approach allows any `List[Map[String, String]]`. It can also help avoid [primitive obsession](https://refactoring.guru/smells/primitive-obsession). Which one you choose depends on your use case.